# Why does IIS return 404 when an unsupported verb is used?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-405

IIS traditionally returns HTTP 404 in case there's some URI path configured to accept POST requests but a GET request is sent to that URI path. Looks like there's HTTP 405 code specifically for such scenario and so it looks like IIS behaves wrong.

Is there any design reason why IIS returns HTTP 404 instead of HTTP 405?